# Почему не устанавливается стиль на ProgressBar в Android?

Tags: android, progress-bar

Файл стиля:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/androd">
        <item android:id="@+id/background">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:width="24dp"
                    android:color="#fff"
                    android:dashWidth="4dp"
                    android:dashGap="4dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    
        <item android:id="@+id/progress">
            <clip
                android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="start">
                <shape android:shape="line">
                    <stroke
                        android:width="24dp"
                        android:color="#2196F3"
                        android:dashWidth="4dp"
                        android:dashGap="4dp" />
                </shape>
            </clip>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Разметка `ProgressBar`:

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/stopPlayButton"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/horizontal_p_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>
```

ProgressBar просто не видно

Upd: Не работало почему то только с моими размерами, с другими работает :/

Comment: предоставьте первый фрагмент в виде кода, а не изображения, пжлст

Comment: не вставляется полностью

Comment: @Tosha, что значит не вставляется? это просто код) Так же желательно показать что вы хотите в итоге получить.

Comment: вставляю все, а в виде кода вставляется только часть, вторую почему то не видно. Мне надо применить стиль к прогрессбару, как то, но самый простой код не работает

Comment: вот отсюда копировал, "Пунктирный ProgressBar" http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/progressbar_horizontal.php

Comment: а какие вы размеры ставили?

Comment: из-за длины не работало почему то, моя 24dp была в стиле, поставил 20dp, как на сайте, и заработало